# Best way to invest money for an year if I will leaving the country?

Tags: united-states, money-market

My US visa expires next year and I have about 50k in savings that I want to invest for a year. I like Marcus by Goldmansachs plan. They seem to offer 3.1% on 5-year deposit. But how do I withdraw the money from the plan if I am no longer in US? I might not even have a bank account in US then.

PS: the 1 year plan of Marcus offers 2.75%. After taxes I am assuming it will be 1.92%(30% tax), which is less than the inflation rate in US(https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/inflation-cpi) 2.25%.

With the 5 year plan, I am a tad bit closer at beating inflation at 2.17% after taxes.

Comment: Are you planning on coming back? If not, why invest in the US? Not trying to be anti-patriotic but couldn't you reinvest your money in banks in your home country? I don't know the rates in your home country but I'd assume it'd be better than the US (since US rates are comparatively lower than other countries).

Comment: So my employer might move me to London or Toronto when my Visa expires. After I been outside the US for a year, I have the option of coming back on an L1 visa. That is why I am looking at US's inflation rate. In my home country, the inflation is way off the charts lol.

Comment: This is rather funny. Do you know that a foreign citizen investment in USA stock capital gains is tax-free?   If you hold any USA niche market stock (that other country cannot live without) or Berkshire-hathaway-B, the rebound after the bear is way better than your risk-averse bond investment.

Comment: " They seem to offer 3.1% on 5-year deposit. " - nice. Now start searching. I get 12% on my conservative fixed term deposits.

Comment: I would choose either between 1. Stocks (10% return on investment on average during the past 100 years in the US) or 2. Real Estate (10% on average historically but with more fees like maintenance/repairs/property tax)

Comment: 1 AND 2 may really bite you in the next year in the current situation. Big time.

Comment: @mootmoot You're going to need to source that claim - depending on the tax treaty in question, mostly capital gains are taxable first in the country of residence. 'foreign citizens' in the US may still be residents for US tax purposes, and regardless, they will otherwise likely pay tax in their home country.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon  Actually it is truth and it does make sense : US citizen must pay profit gains from stock and they are also allowed to deduct loses from tax.

Comment: @mootmoot That has nothing to do with your initial claim, that "a foreign citizen investment in USA stock capital gains is tax-free". [Again, this is incorrect; 'source of income' for capital gains on non-'real property' [ie: non-land]  is typically based on country of residence, so a French citizen resident in France owning US stocks would pay French taxes on taxable gains if sold for a property. All this depends on tax treaty, but your blanket statement would only potentially be correct for a jurisdiction which itself did not tax capital gains [ie: 'tax-haven' style countries].

Comment: @mootmoot Also I will point out that you cannot infer foreign tax results from US tax results; only 2 countries in the world require citizens to file full tax returns regardless of whether they are residents - Eritrea and the US.

Answer (score -1):

Most countries require residency to hold a financial account. Otherwise the country is an offshore country.

A non-resident might hold a U.S. account as a U.S. state-organized LLC company that is IRS taxed as a C-corporation.

Comment: "Most countries require residency to hold a financial account." . NO. Definitely not. I maintain financial accounts in multiple countries - mostly because of financial interest (i.e. collecting rent on multiple rental properties). This, though is NOT residence. And I am not sure you would call germany an offshore country.

Comment: And I knew an american once that had some houses in the US and he was living in germany for multiple years and STILL had accounts in the USA. Again, no residency.

Comment: Well here is one link: https://thunfinancial.com/home/american-expat-financial-advice-research-articles/us-brokerage-accounts-american-expats-closed-2015/ . Other links could explain what off-shore banking is.

Comment: I'm live in the U.S and am a U.S. citizen. I can't hold a UK bank account except in an off-shore jurisdiction such as Isle of Man or the Channel Islands. Well, unless I lie on the banking application. For investment in the U.S. from a foreign country, there is no off-shore jurisdiction. The foreign investor could form a U.S. LLC company, with a registered agent, and then invest in the U.S.

Comment: Yes. And that is because many do not want to deal with US citizens because your jurisdictions tries to force every other country to ALSO follow US laws when you have US customers. Result? Thanks, we do not deal with you. But the question is about a FOREIGNER (not US citizen) leaving the US for some time, so - totally different.